# Alignment In SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, zstack

I'm new to SwiftUI. I'm designing a widget for size systemMedium.
I'm getting stuck in spacing,
If I reduce the size of the Violet Container, Then the rest UI is not aligning properly
Here is My Code

```
case .systemMedium:
    ZStack {
        Color("Yellow")
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
            PercentageMediumView()
                .padding(.trailing, 80.0)
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
            Last14MediumView()
        
        }
    }
```

Here is what it looks like,
[My Code Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5U3n.png)
I need to eliminate that space(from arrow)

What I need Design
[My Actual Design Needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAY4d.png)

Comment: remove Spacer() and try.

Comment: I tried, but nothing worked

Comment: you have a trailing padding of 80 points. remove Spacer(), and reduce padding size.

Comment: As far as I can see, the Spacer() "pushes" the Last14MediumView() to the right, given the code, I would expect Last14MediumView() to "touch" the right edge. I'm not sure what the "correct" solution here would be, given that I don't really understand your constraints, but try putting another Spacer() after the Last14MediumView() – it would "balance" the Spacer before the Last14MediumView().

Comment: I should also add that it is unclear what ".padding(.trailing, 80.0)" is there to accomplish, given the design spec.

Comment: Provide a [mre] so that people can experiment with it.